# Undefined index even though the key is declared

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, concatenation

I have this php script that generates a multi-dimensional associative array:

```
<?php
$a=array();
$x = 0;
while($x < 2)
{
    $a["color"] = array();
    if($x == 0)
    {
        $a["color"]["price"] = "25";
    }
    else
    {
        $a["color"]["price"] .= "5";
    }
    $x += 1;
}
print_r($a);

?>
```

I always get `Notice: Undefined index: price`.

I've clearly defined the `price` index in the if statement, so why is this happening?

Comment: `$a["color"]["price"] .= "5";` You're concat'ing to `$a["color"]["price"]` which doesn't exist yet/no more

Comment: Dear closevoter using Typo justification, the OP did not slip on the keyboard and accidentally type 22 characters: `$a["color"] = array();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are purging the `price` element on every iteration with `$a["color"] = array();`

Therefore, you have no `price` to concatenate to.

Perhaps you are thinking that the subarray must be declared before child elements can be declared.  This is not necessary with arrays, but it is necessary for objects.  Here's a [demo](https://3v4l.org/mmLdJ) -- I have commented out the lines of code that prevent the error.

---

You might consider this alternative snippet: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/YkOCq)) ([Demo2](https://3v4l.org/tV6f4))

```
$a = [];
for ($x = 0; $x < 2; ++$x) {
    if (!$x) {
        $a["color"]["price"] = "25";
    } else {
        $a["color"]["price"] .= "5";
    }
}
var_export($a);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'color' => 
  array (
    'price' => '255',
  ),
)
```

I must say, though, that I find it odd that you are concatenating the price instead of adding it.  To add, you can just replace the `.` with `+`.

Comment: Show me a 3v4l.org demo link and I'll have a look at what you mean.

Comment: Here's the [Demo](https://3v4l.org/6NfOm)( it's not really a demo it's just my code with comments)

Comment: https://3v4l.org/lviAI  <-- some good tips in here.